# wp-login.php redirects to server site, not locahost

Tags: php, wordpress

I downloaded all the wordpress files from the server.

And imported the database phpmyadmin locally.

And I can enter the site local. But when I do:

```
http://localhost:8080/nieuwdenhaag/wp-login.php
```

Then I don't see the login page of localhost. But I will be redirected to de admin of the server site.

So are there are some files that I have to change, except of course the wp-config file?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the issue

1. You can change the **siteurl** and **home** fields from your database according to your local address (http://localhost:8080/nieuwdenhaag). In that case, you've to go **phpMyadmin > select your database > select wp_options table and then change**. Please see the attached image to understand properly.[![**siteurl** and **home** fields][1]][1]
2. You can add the two constant in wp_config.php file.

   ```
    define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:8080/nieuwdenhaag');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:8080/nieuwdenhaag');
   ```

Thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTHHr.png

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% a WordPress expert but I did have to do something similar to this recently to migrate a site and also get it working on my localhost to fix a few bugs. What I did was use this plugin (https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) to export -> to a file and then import it on your localhost!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After download the complete site from the live server you have to change the url in the database in the `options` table. The parameters are `siteurl` and `home`. After that you should be able to login to your admin.

In Wordpress all URLs are stored directly in the database. You have to search a plugin that replaces your URL in the database that you can see all files (Better Search Replace) for example.

Comment: Thank that was the trick. I can login. But I think I have to use the plugin migrate. Because the other links will not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following search and replace script for that.

https://interconnectit.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

It has a nice UI using which you can update your URLs. This will also update the URL in various plug-ins metadata.

Don’t forget to delete the script after using it.